# PlayReady DRM on Wowza with custom streaming app

Tags: java, android, drm, playready

I have build a custom app(Android platform) that live streams my mic and camera to a wowza server. I want to extend the Microsoft PlayReady SDK (for securing the content),but I am a little bit confused about how to do it.

Far as I read here (see link below),I only need to follow the steps indicated there,and that is it. Or this tutorial works only with GoCoder?
http://www.wowza.com/forums/content....28PlayReady%29

After I read the PlayReady documentation,I found out that I also need to implement some code in my app(but it doesn't mention for which server I stream,or something else.Just how to implement their SDK). My app functionality is similar to GoCoders. It streams the media using an rtsp connection,and the video is a H.264 format.

My question is what is the proper way to implement the PlayReady SDK and make it work with my app and the wowza servers (I mean crypting/securing my videos)?

Thank you,

Bob

P.S. My app is not public yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bob - DRM can be pretty complex and in most cases suited best suited for high value content, if you want to do that route there is some lifting to do.

The article you noted above tells you how to set up the BuyDRM PlayReady module on Wowza Streaming Engine (with any incoming source, not just GoCoder).  Once you have enabled PlayReady on the Wowza server, you will not need to do anything more in the app as far as encoding goes, the encryption is all done on the server. What you will need however is a custom player that can play back this encrypted stream, as well as a PlayReady key server to manage access.

You may want to consider a somewhat lighter solution, like secure token and streamlock which is focused more on preventing unauthorized playback and transport encryption rather than content encryption.